# How to fix documentation format in VS Code for python kite?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, latex, pytorch, kite

I am using pytorch in VSCode but the format of the documentation is just terrible (see image). Do you have any pointers on how we can set the documentation format in VSCode? I believe that documentation contains LaTeX formulas.... [Check the image in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2YZk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently nothing you can do. It contains LaTeX and the extension does not render them as such.